# How does the fisheye projection model work?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

This is my first contact with the fisheye model/lens type and I'm trying to understand how it works.

I put some sphere on a circle at different angles 0(red), 30(vert),  60(blue), 90(jaune), 120(magenta),  150(cyan), 180(white) degrees (see image 1). After that, I did the render. I remark that the sphere did not project in the same order. At 0 degree, I put the red sphere  and at the 180 degrees, I put the white sphere. Can someone tell me why I did not get spheres in the same order ?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: Very interesting! They appear to be in the right spot to me in your image. The spheres on the bottom of the curve just appear closer, making them seem further up it.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, Normally, i have to obtain the red at the right extremity and the white one at the left extremity.

Comment: What do you mean by "obtain"?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise, in my case "obtain =have", I mean the result should be the red at  the right extremity and the white one at the left extremity

Comment: Apparently not. That might be how they are set up in the scene, but it is not how it renders because of your settings. Also, "obtain" means "to acquire"

Comment: In normal perspective you know that far objects are smaller thus closer together, that's clear. Its nicely seen on a straight rails in the distance etc. With fish-eye this effect is much more pronounced because you also get distorsion. Thats why the red and white are not on the edges. To get better tests you should render grids of lines, it will be more clear that this.

Comment: @Jerryno, I am not sure, but it seems a bug in blender

Comment: @Jerryno, I try for different values of focal and degrees and the result still the same.